# In sales order email i'm getting "Pay with Credit/Debit Card or Paypa" twice." magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, sales-order, payment-methods

In my sales order email i'm getting

```
"Pay with Credit/Debit Card or Paypa" twice.
```

How to remove `"Pay with Credit/Debit Card or Paypa and Payer Email"` that i marked in attached image. Please let me know?

[image]

Comment: Please any one help this